# Placement of Licensing in Apple Sample Code - Swift

Tags: licensing, software

I was going through a tutorial on Apple/Swift and they show a sample project which they offer users to download. On the Swift file, they show:

```
/* See LICENSE folder for this sample's licensing information */
```

After clicking to the licensing information, I see:

> Copyright © 2019 Apple Inc.
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

I am confused where this licensing information should be located in my project, especially if I am modifying/adding to the sample code. Also, which parts of the license need to be located in the project.

Comment: Are you asking which of the above paragraphs must be included? For example the copyright notice and the permission notice seems pretty clear. The only possible question I see is whether or not the license requires the final paragraph, the warranty disclaimer, to be included. This license is also commonly called the "MIT license" so if you search for that you will get more information about it.

Comment: Where do I place the license? Do I put it in a separate file or do I put it in the same file as the code which I added to/and modified?

Comment: This is the MIT license. See also: [Can I move an in-line license to a file?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/can-i-move-an-in-line-license-to-a-file) and other questions related to MIT.

Comment: Notice the text is pretty broad "shall be included in all copies" does not impose any specific requirements on *where* it is inicluded, just that it *is* included. It only gets tricky when you consider binary-only distributions, since normally when you compile, all source code comments are removed, so you need to find some other way to include it in that case.